# How do I create a EBS snapshot without downtime to the instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, snapshot, amazon-ebs

Is it possible to create a snapshot of an EBS Volume without downtime via Terraform?
I am currently looking at documentation about resource aws_dlm_lifecycle_policy.
(https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dlm_lifecycle_policy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it is possible. DLM lifecycle policy just automates snapshot creation.
Snapshots are created asynchronously, even from an attached volume which is in use. Consult with official AWS documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html